# unable to use prompt package in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, prompt

I am a beginner in nodeJS. I wanted to take some input in the console in nodeJS and came accross the package prompt. Below is the code  I am using :

```
var prompt = require('prompt');
prompt.start();
prompt.get(['offset', 'limit'], function (err, result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

But I am unable to enter the second argument. What am I doing wrong?!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's a known bug about this on their [issues](https://github.com/flatiron/prompt/issues/132) tracker.

It's allegedly fixed in node v5.x, can you upgrade?